# how do I request a user and save the user in a Foreignkey field of a model

Tags: python, django

When I do this exactly as provided below, a shipping address object is created without the customer assigned in the shipping address foreignkey field, I can add it from the admin panel manually but I'm not able to make it work through code

```
**models.py**

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)

class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    address_one = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address_two = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

**views.py**

def checkout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ShippingForm(request.POST)
        customer = request.user.customer
        if form.is_valid():

            # how to add the customer object to the foreignkey field of the shipping address
            

            form.save()
            return redirect('store:checkout_shipping')
        else:
            form = ShippingForm()

    else:
        form = ShippingForm()

    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

Comment: Please als o show `ShippingForm`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Dw fixed it. Thx a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```
ShippingAddress.objects.get(customer=customer)
```

This returns a `ShippingAddress`, but

```
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

requires a `CustomUser`. These are incompatible, so you cannot assign them.

But you are already getting the user:

```
customer = request.user.customer
```

Just reduce this a little:

```
user = request.user
```

now you have a user object.

I am assuming that you have correctly set up the `CustomUser` class in the Django settings.

Comment: getting just the user won't work, the customer has an order object associated with it, when I assign the customer manually to the shipping address from admin panel it works but I'm missing something I really have no clue what I'm messing up.

Comment: @riderken Your original question doesn't mention an "order object" nor an `Order` class. It sounds like you are missing information for me to be able to answer your question. Please edit your question to include any details that are needed.

Comment: I changed it as u asked